# What do you call it when someone says they’re not going to mention a thing?

Tags: rhetorical-devices

Is there a name for the sort of expression where someone would say something like...

“I’m not going to mention the ridiculous hat they’re wearing.”

Or

“I could make a joke about footballers diving around on the floor after smaller incidents, but I won’t.”

By saying they’re not going to mention a topic they have mentioned the topic.

It’s used fairly often so I was wondering if there is a word or name for this kind of phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[apophasis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apophasis)

> the raising of an issue by claiming not to mention it (as in "we won't discuss his past crimes")

Comment: Thanks for this. Is apophasis also the correct term for when people are being mean and say something in an ironic way like “I hope this really specific bad thing doesn’t happen to you” when actually they only bring it up as an example of something they would like to happen. I have seen people tweeting about Trump today saying “I hope he doesn’t die from Covid” etc... when in fact they mean the opposite. Or is that something else?

Comment: Their motives do not matter.